# Visual force tab delete

Tags: visualforce, tab

Can we able to remove visual force tab?
My requirement is i want to delete one visualforce page completly.when i am deleting it it is referencing to visualforce tab. Then i tried to remove that tab it is showing vice versa. Not letting me to delete vf page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the question has been answered, please mark one of the responses as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the Visualforce page says in the apex:page tag: tabstyle="CustomTab__Tab" or similar, then it will give an error.

Remove the tabstyle part of the page tag in the page, and then delete the tab.

Comment: Nothing like good old circular references ...

Answer (score 1):

That sounds unusual that the visualforce page is referencing the tab when you try to delete the tab.  Could you post up the exact error?

If the page is somehow referencing the tab then you could just delete the content of the page so it saves as just an empty visualforce page.  Then you should be able to delete the tab followed by the visualforce page.

The other option would be to use the migration tools and create a destructiveChanges.xml file that contains both the tab and the page.  More details on this [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Propagating_Destructive_Changes)